# Row sum for large term-document matrix / simple_triplet_matrix ?? {tm package}

Tags: r, text-mining

So I have a very large term-document matrix:

```
> class(ph.DTM)
[1] "TermDocumentMatrix"    "simple_triplet_matrix"

> ph.DTM
A term-document matrix (109996 terms, 262811 documents)

Non-/sparse entries: 3705693/28904453063
Sparsity           : 100%
Maximal term length: 191 
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

How do I get the rowSum (frequency) of each term? I tried:

```
> apply(ph.DTM, 1, sum)
Error in vector(typeof(x$v), nr * nc) : vector size cannot be NA
In addition: Warning message:
In nr * nc : NAs produced by integer overflow
```

Obviously, I know about `removeSparseTerms`:

```
ph.DTM2 <- removeSparseTerms(ph.DTM, 0.99999)
```

Which cuts down the size a bit:

```
> ph.DTM2
A term-document matrix (28842 terms, 262811 documents)

Non-/sparse entries: 3612620/7576382242
Sparsity           : 100%
Maximal term length: 24 
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

But I still cannot apply any matrix-related functions to it:

```
> as.matrix(ph.DTM2)
Error in vector(typeof(x$v), nr * nc) : vector size cannot be NA
In addition: Warning message:
In nr * nc : NAs produced by integer overflow
```

**How can I just get a simple row sum on this object?? Thanks!!**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

OK, after some more Google'ing, I came across the `slam` package, which enables:

```
ph.DTM3 <- rollup(ph.DTM, 2, na.rm=TRUE, FUN = sum)
```

Which works.

Comment: Digging around, I found slam's `row_sums` function, which appears to be a bit faster.

Answer (score 12):

As alluded to by @badpanda in one of the comments, `slam` now has the `row_sums` and `col_sums` functions for sparse arrays:

```
slam::row_sums(dtm, na.rm = T)
slam::col_sums(tdm, na.rm = T)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think:

```
 rowSums(as.matrix(ph.DTM))
```

Would work as well.

Comment: For very large matrices this seems to produce the same error.

Comment: @badpanda Without a definition of "very large" your comment is not useful.  Also was Ray Bao's answer useful?  Please provide specific information that is of use to others.

Comment: Slam's row_sums function (as per bskaggs) worked for me. My TDM was ~300,000 terms x 100,000 documents.

Comment: @TylerRinker I was trying rowSums to do this, but I received the error 'cannot allocate vector of size 33.7 Gb'. I'm surprised that the vector would be this big, but can you shed any light? dim(dtm) returns 137090 x 32981