# Transform from class "simple_triplet_matrix" to class "matrix"

Tags: r, matrix, tm

I am trying to **convert** the following Simple Triplet Matrix created with `TermDocumentMatrix()` of the `tm` package

```
A term-document matrix (317443 terms, 86960 documents)

Non-/sparse entries: 18472230/27586371050
Sparsity           : 100%
Maximal term length: 653 
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

of class

```
[1] "TermDocumentMatrix"    "simple_triplet_matrix"
```

**to a dense matrix**.

But

```
dense <- as.matrix(tdm)
```

generates the error

```
Error in vector(typeof(x$v), nr * nc) : vector size cannot be NA
In addition: Warning message:
In nr * nc : NAs produced by integer overflow
```

I can't really understand the error and warning message. Trying to replicate the error on a small dataset with

```
library(tm)
data("crude")
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude)
as.matrix(tdm)
```

doesn't produce the same issue. I saw from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21921618/1707938) that a similar problem was solved through the `slam` package (even though the question was about a sum operation and not a transformation into a dense matrix). I browsed the `slam` documentation but I couldn't find any specific function to transform an object of class `simple_triplet_matrix` into an object of class `matrix`.

Comment: Number of rows times number of columns, `nr * nc`,  is too large for the available storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an error because as commented you reach the limit of the integer limit, normal since you have huge number of documents.. This reproduces the error :

```
as.integer(.Machine$integer.max+1)
[1] NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Function `vector` which takes an integer as parameter fails since it second parameter is NA.

One solution is to redefine `as.matrix.simple_triplet_matrix` without calling `vector`. For example:

```
as.matrix.simple_triplet_matrix <- 
function (x, ...) 
{
  nr <- x$nrow
  nc <- x$ncol
  ## old line: y <- matrix(vector(typeof(x$v), nr * nc), nr, nc)
  y <- matrix(0, nr, nc)  ## 
  y[cbind(x$i, x$j)] <- x$v
  dimnames(y) <- x$dimnames
  y
}
```

But I am not sure it is a good idea to coerce to a matrix such sparse matrix(100%).

**EDIT**

One idea is to use `saparseMatrix` from `Matrix` package. Here an example where I compare the objects generated by each coercion. You gain a factor of 10 at lease ( I think regarding your very sparse matrix , you will gain more) by using `sparseMatrix`. Moreover, Addition and multiplication are supported by sparse Matrix.

```
require(tm)
data("crude")
dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude,
                          control = list(weighting = weightTfIdf,
                                         stopwords = TRUE))
library(Matrix)
Dense <- sparseMatrix(dtm$i,dtm$j,x=dtm$v)
dense <- as.matrix(dtm)
## check sizes 
floor(as.numeric(object.size(dense)/object.size(Dense)))
## addistion and multiplication are supported
Dense+Dense
Dense*Dense
```

Comment: Mmm, I need a dense matrix to do some matrix operation on it (multiplication in particular)... Are you suggesting would be better to operate directly on the triplet matrix?

Comment: yes ! it is just a  list in the long format dtm[i,j,value]. Try to see if you can do matrix operations in this format.

Comment: I tried the function on my tdm: `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 205.7 Gb`

Comment: you reach R limits! that's why I am saying no need to coerce to a matrix !

Comment: I guess Odysseus could have had similar feelings when passing the Pillars of Hercules...

Comment: @CptNemo I don't get what do you mean. But you can see my edit. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your edit helped. I was able to multiply the matrices.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48731/discussion-between-agstudy-and-cptnemo)

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem.  I'm not sure if my problem is identical, but when combining a sparse matrix with a dense matrix I got a similar error message `NAs produced by integer overflow`.  I was able to fix it by converting the dense matrix to single precision using `as.single`.  I think the "overflowing integers" are caused by operations in the `sparseMatrix` package that somehow truncate double precision values leaving leftover digits.